# Multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue in $A^tA$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I have a fat matrix $A$ $\in\mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$ (with $m<n$), is it true that $A^tA$ has a zero eigenvalue of multiplicity of $n-m$? I am not sure if it is true but I tried few variation to contradict it without a succes.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the underlying field $\mathbb F$ as well as the rank of $A$. If $A$ is a real matrix, then $Ax=0$ if and only if $A^tAx=0$, because
$$
Ax=0\Rightarrow A^tAx=0\Rightarrow \|Ax\|^2=x^tA^tAx=0\Rightarrow Ax=0.
$$
Therefore the nullity of $A^tA$ is precisely the nullity of $A$, which is equal to $n-\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and is bounded below by $n-m$. So, the zero eigenvalue of $A^tA$ has multiplicity $n-m$ if and only if $A$ has full row rank.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\text{rank}(A) \le \min\{m,n\} = m$, the rank-nullity theorem implies that the nullity of $A$ is $\ge n-m$. Since $\text{nullspace}(A) \subseteq \text{nullspace}(A^\top A)$, we have $\text{nullity}(A^\top A) \ge \text{nullity}(A) \ge n-m$, so the multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue of $A^\top A$ is at least $n-m$.